# error on get /me with access_token facebook php sdk 3.1.1

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

If i try:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

It works. But if I make a call:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?access_token='.MY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

It doesn't work:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /home/jill/web/public/condividi/libs/facebook/base_facebook.php on line 1033